# bootstrap 4; float row of fontawesome text inside row of other text

Tags: bootstrap-4, font-awesome, overlapping

I am putting together a profile page. I have a top row with the person's name. I have a row below it with a star-rating. [HERE's THE JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/ryanskene/1Lq44p43/1/) and here's the code.

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="d-flex flex-row justify-content-around">
        <div class="d-flex flex-column flex-1 text-center mr-2">
          <img class="img-fluid profile-pic"
              src="{{ url_for('static', filename='img/user-images/') }}{{current_user.id}}/profile/{{profile_pic.filename}}"
              alt="Image Failed to Load">
        </div>
        <div class="d-flex flex-column flex-1 ml-2">
          <div class="d-flex flex-row">
            <div class="flex-column ">
              <div class="flex-row text-left profile-name">
                Ashley Eggerton
                <div>
                  <div class="flex-row" style="float: left">

                    <i class="fa fa-star" style="font-size: 5vw;" id="star-rating" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    <i class="fa fa-star" style="font-size: 5vw;" id="star-rating" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    <i class="fa fa-star" style="font-size: 5vw;" id="star-rating" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                  </div>
                </div>
```

What I have been trying to do is get the star-rating row to float inside profile name row. Basically, I want the stars to be flush with the name, and with certain of the name fonts (like "y" and "g") to overhand the star rating.

I have tried column containers and various combinations of absolute/relative position and float; no success. Any change I make seems to result in the most bottom row "Book Your Event ..." overlapping the top two rows.

Any help with this specific problem would be appreciated, as well as any link to tutorials on absolute/relative position would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you explain this with different words, I don't understand what you mean: "get the star-rating row to float inside profile name row. Basically, I want the stars to be flush with the name, and with certain of the name fonts (like "y" and "g") to overhand the star rating."

Comment: np. e.g. the margin of the top div is pushed down to the bottom of the "y" in Ashley. the stars cannot go higher than the bottom of the top div. therefore, the stars cannot go higher than the bottom of the "y" in ashley. I want the middle div with the gold stars to overlap the top div, so the gold stars reach to the bottom of the "Ashle" letters, which means the bottom of "y" would overlap the stars. clearer?